# How to get the NA rate by column in Tableau Desktop?

Tags: duplicates, tableau-api

I try to get a simple thing with Tableau, the % of null value by column of my dataset.

But each time I put my dimensions on my columns it displays all of possible values of this dimension, it's impossible to make the Python's equivalent of `dataframe.isna().sum()/len(dataframe)`.

Answer (score 0):

By default Tableau visualizes all possible values.

Assuming you have this kind of data:

```
ID  Category
1   A
2   B
3   C
4   D
5   E
6   F
7   
8   
9   
10
```

You can get your Rate with a simple Calculated field:

[image]